# Caching user information once user logs-in

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, caching, asp.net-mvc-5

I have users with different Roles. I want to deliver restricted view according to roles of the users. I have something in my Code which checks roles:

```
bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(currentUser.Id,"admin");
bool isEmployee = UserManager.IsInRole(currentUser.Id,"employee");
```

For above code to work, I need to instantiate currentUser. In other words I need to catch the information of the current user that is logged in. I tried something like `var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();` and many other but can't find the working code. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

**Update:**

here's my complete method code. y'all might wanna see until i check the above example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var user = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 
    bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(user, "admin"); 
    bool isEmployee = UserManager.IsInRole(user, "employee"); 
    if (isAdmin)
    { 
        return View(db.Customers.ToList()); 
    }
    else
    { 
        var restricted = db.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstName == "John");
        return View(restricted); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId() should work just fine. Is it a brand new MVC5 project?

Comment: This is what the `Authorize` attribute is for.  Look at [this example](http://forums.asp.net/t/1791288.aspx)

Comment: here's my complete method code. y'all might wanna see until i check the above example.

public ActionResult Index()
{
var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(user, "admin");
bool isEmployee = UserManager.IsInRole(user, "employee");

if(isAdmin){
 return View(db.Customers.ToList());
}
else{
var restricted = from c in db.Customers
where c.FirstName == "John"
select c;

return View(restricted);
}

}

Answer (score 3):

`[Authorize]` attribute should be implemented in the desired restricted actionController method. The example is below.

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

This controller method is limited to the User with Role Admin. Furthermore, same action controller method could be included twice with different authorize tag.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow figured out the solution. Here's the working code.

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    return View(db.Customers.ToList());
}
else
{
    return View(db.MyUserInfo.ToList());
}
```